# how to loops the code in try and catch section in TCL

Tags: exception, try-catch, tcl

I have TCL code which i want to loop in case i receive "Connection closed by foreign host"

## connecting to the router (IOL router)

```
Telnet to routem PC
connect sys -match_max 500000 "telnet $linux_machine $port"
# using the system passed login credentials
receive sys  {login:} 120
sleep 5
transmit sys "$ta_user_id\r"
receive sys  {Password: $}
transmit sys "$ta_user_passwd\r"
receive sys  {%$}
transmit sys "su\r"
receive sys  {Password: $} 20
transmit sys "$root_passwd\r"
```

log
log of failure scenario

```
++++ 05:13:50 sys Control::connect +++
Connect: sys -match_max 500000 {telnet ssr-lnx-iol 5012}
+--- 05:13:50 ---
++++ 05:13:50 sys Control::receive +++
Trying 172.25.195.183...
Connected to ssr-lnx-iol.
Escape character is '^]'.
Fedora release 9 (Sulphur)
Kernel 2.6.25-14.fc9.i686 on an i686 (0)
login: 
--- 05:14:01 ---
++++ 05:14:06 sys Control::transmit +++
Transmit: root
+--- 05:14:06 ---
++++ 05:14:06 sys Control::receive +++
root
Password: 
devtest-
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: It's a shame it isn't plain Expect; that can do this sort of thing easy.

Comment: @DonalFellows please explain

Comment: The problem is that the script is using commands that appear to be application specific, rather than just standard Tcl commands or commands from well-known extensions (e.g., Expect). That makes helping you very difficult; though app-specific commands are _great_, they can vary wildly and we'd need to read documentation (or source, at a pinch) to really advise.

Comment: The key is that you're looking for a way to wait on several different strings from the communications channel at once, and take different actions depending on which one is received. We can't guess the syntax for doing that based on what you've posted.